# Explanation of Source-Absorption Theorem Example

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, current-source

In the section on the *Source-Absorption Theorem*, my textbook has the following example:

[image]

I was wondering: If the voltage $$v_\pi = - v_e,$$ then why do we get $$g_m v_\pi = g_m v_e$$ instead of $$g_m v_\pi = -g_m v_e$$?

I would appreciate it if someone could please take the time to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the word *away*: since \$v_\pi<0\$, the current has magnitude \$v_\pi g_m\$ and is flowing in the opposite direction from what the arrow is pointing in the small signal schematic, so from the emitter to the collector, that is grounded.

Total current \$i_e\$ is then made of two components, one flowing in \$r_\pi\$, the other flowing in the collector current source. The latter current can "luckily" be modeled with a resistor which resistance is \$1/g_m\$, since it is proportional to the emitter voltage itself.

When solving a circuit, and particularly currents, always keep in mind that a negative result is nothing more than a positive result, flowing in the opposite direction with respect the reference positive direction, that is assumed when starting to tackle the problem.